# I get error message from apple while uploading to testflight for testing

Tags: ios, swift

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "LifeTap-Staging" 0.5.4 (76). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in Lifetap-staging: determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, leaveGroup, lookupAdConversionDetails:, receiveMessages, sendMessage. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Best regards,

The App Store Team

The pods i use in file are

pod 'Moya'
pod 'Kingfisher', '4.10.1'
pod 'SnapKit'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '7.2'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '7.2'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '7.2'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '5.0.2'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Tags'
pod 'SkeletonView'
pod 'ZFRippleButton'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
pod 'DatePicker'
pod 'DateTimePicker'
pod 'XMPPFramework'
pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

I had no issue till last day but today unfortunately i get this error from apple through an email while uploading app to test flight. (I have not edited any code)

Comment: Based on Apple's comment, you may be using a library that is not available for public use. If so, delete it or add the required permissions. If not, try changing the names of the methods that are called there in the message. They say: " If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions". Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to know which library is not available for public use?. The app was fine till last day no issues.

Comment: When I change the method names that are flagged, it works fin

Comment: Did you find out where determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler was coming from? Many thanks!

Comment: No. To be honest I have no clue why just one morning apple found these errors

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: @Demosthese . Rename those methods and you will be fine. If you get any idea why this happens please explain

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I don't have methods named like that :D

Comment: I have no clue why that error is. If any could explain i would appreciate that!

Comment: Do found any solution ?

Comment: Yes Changed the names of the functions they mentioned